# Can I output string at the end of Gulp pipeline instead of file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

From the gulp task in `Foundation for Emails`

```
function pages() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages',
      layouts: 'src/layouts',
      partials: 'src/partials',
      helpers: 'src/helpers'
    }))
    .pipe(inky())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}
```

I want to return the output as a string and not write as a file. Is this possible? I know I can input string to a gulp pipeline using `gulp-file`.